# why do i recieve index out of range error?

Tags: python

I was trying to do the Fibonacci sequence but instead of doing the third number with the 2 past numbers y want to do the 4th number with the last 3 numbers
my first code was this:

```
def tribonacci(signature, n):
    a, b, c = signature
    tribo = [signature[0],signature[1],signature[2]]

    for i in range(n):
        s = a+b+c
        a = b
        b = c
        c = s
        tribo.append(c)
    return tribo

print(tribonacci([1, 1, 1], 10))
```

I receive [1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 17, 31, 57, 105, 193, 355, 653] which mean that the sequence starts with the number 3, not with the first 1. but I don't want to append the "signature" values to the array, but instead, start adding each value to the array

so I tried this code instead:

```
def tribonacci(signature, n):
    tribo = []

    for i in range(0, n):
        a = signature[i]
        b = signature[2*i]
        c = signature[3*i]
        s = a+b+b
        a = b
        b = c
        c = s
        tribo.append(c)
    return tribo


print(tribonacci([1, 1, 1], 10))
```

I was expecting to get this [1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 17, 31, 57, 105], but the error index out of range appears

Comment: In your second code you try to access `signature` at various indexes. But you never actually change that list, so it remains `[1, 1, 1]` at all times (which means that any access at an index > 2 will fail).

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, you're dealing with two different lists: `tribo` and `signature`. When you increase the index of `i`, you try to take that index from `signature` - but `signature` only has three elements, so when `i*3 > 2`, you get an `IndexError`.

Instead of making two different arrays, the better way to solve this problem would be to use your original code, but then slice the first three elements off of the array you return:

```
def tribonacci(signature, n):
    a, b, c = signature
    ...
    return tribo[3:]
```

Instead of having to have three different variables to store the three elements, you could also utilize python's idea of *negative list incides* (which count from the back instead of from the front). A terser implementation of `tribonacci`, doing that, might look like this:

```
def tribonacci(signature, n):
    tribo = signature[:]  # copy the contents of signature, to start with
    for i in range(n):
        # add the last three elements of tribo together, and append the sum
        tribo.append(
            tribo[-1] + tribo[-2] + tribo[-3]
        )
    return tribo[3:]
```

though this will give you an `IndexError` if the given `signature` is shorter than 3 elements.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is in calling the arrays:

```
for i in range(0, n):
    a = signature[i]
    b = signature[2*i]
    c = signature[3*i]
```

...should be...

```
for i in range(0, n):
    a = signature[i]
    b = signature[1+i]
    c = signature[2+i]
```

Otherwise, when n=10 you will be accessing signature(30), which does not exist.

There are other bugs, too, such as `s=a+b+b` instead of `s=a+b+c`, and this edit alone will not solve the issue, however that is likely why you are receiving out of bounds errors.

The biggest error otherwise is using two different arrays. Your `tribo` array is never initialized with the starting 1's so cannot become the desired result. Trying to keep to your core code, I would simply change the range of the for loop to `(0, n-3)` or use `signature` in place of tribo.

```
def tribonacci(signature, n):
    for i in range(0, n-3):
        a = signature[i]
        b = signature[1+i]
        c = signature[2+i]
        s = a+b+c
        a = b
        b = c
        c = s
        signature.append(c)
    return signature
print(tribonacci([1, 1, 1], 10))
```

Comment: The problem with this solution (the last block of code you put) is that it modifies `signature` in-place, which OP might not want. This could be solved by simply shallow-copying `signature` initially via `signature = signature[:]` at the beginning of the function (though that's kind of hacky)

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Indeed, there a multitude of solutions available, up to OP, depending on desired behavior. I'm assuming that once he figures out the Index OOB error, likely due to the signature[2*i], that he'll continue to play with it afterwards as he pleases.